# Ограничение верхнего значения переменной

Tags: c++, c

Есть 2 переменные

```
int A=180;
int B=230;
```

Мы складываем эти переменные, но значение не должно быть больше `255`.
Можно было бы сделать

```
int C;
C = A+B;
  if(C>255)
C=255;
```

Но нельзя использовать `if`.

Создавать класс и перегружать `operator+` тоже не нужно.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать `if`?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду эффективность, современные компиляторы убирают переходы при оптимизации (проверил на MSVC и gcc).

Comment: Имеется в виду сложение с насыщением (saturation), т.е. `250+6=255`? Или результатом сложения может быть любое число, не большее 255? А сами `A` и `B` могут быть больше 255?

Comment: Думаю, что имеется в виду это решение: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277623/bitwise-saturated-addition-in-c-hw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать и без сравнений. Следующий код справедлив для языка C++ и 4-х байтового `int`:

```
C = (static_cast<bool>(0xFFFFFF00 & C) * 255) | (C & 255);
```

Версия выше будет работать только если **C** — положительное число. Универсальный метод может выглядеть так:

```
auto hasUpperBits = static_cast<bool>(0xFFFFFF00 & C);
auto negative = static_cast<bool>(0x80000000 & C);
C = C & (C*!hasUpperBits | C*negative) | 255*hasUpperBits*!negative;
```

Comment: Для `unsigned int`, вы хотели сказать - ведь про отрицательные значения в условии ничего не сказано...

Comment: @Harry, `int` и `unsigned int` имею одинаковый размер, так что это не важно. Но код выше будет работать только если сумма положительна, это да

Comment: Именно это и имею в виду - что при отрицательных значениях будем получать все те же 255.

Comment: @Harry, добавил универсальную формулу

Comment: `auto`, `static_cast` ... имхо, в старом стиле будет даже элегантнее (+ не важен размер `int`а): `bool hasUpperBits = ~0xFFu & C;   bool negative = C >> (sizeof(C) * 8 - 1);`

Comment: @ixSci Снимаю шляпу!...

Answer (score 9):

Отказ от использования `if` возможен только в таких случаях:

- наивный преподаватель. Но это решается административными методами.
- внутреннее чувство несовершенности. Это решается психологом.
- нужда в оптимизации, так как профайлер сказал, что это узкое место. Вот этим мы и займемся.

Раз это узкое место, то значит оно часто вызывается, например в цикле. Есть ряд задач на переконвертирование картинок (видео), где нужно выполнять подобную операцию, например, изменять яркость. И современные процессоры предоставляют готовую инструкцию, которая как раз подобное и делает - складывает числа с насыщением. Имя этим инструкциям - [SSE2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2). Эти инструкции поддерживаются практически всеми существующими на данный момент процессорами, а 8 винда и старше даже не будет устанавливаться, если процессор их не поддерживает. Так что тут бояться не стоит.

Но не нужно думать, что нужно будет писать явно ассемблерный код. Для этого придумали чудную штуку - интринсики. Это такие "магические" функции, которые компилятор знает и вместо них, почти один к одному подставляет ассемблерный код.

Перейдем ближе к делу.  В приведенном в вопросе случае нужна функция [_mm_adds_epu8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hahyddy(v=vs.90).aspx). Как видно с текста, поддерживается даже 2005 студией (а также всеми современными gcc). Эта функция умеет одновременно складывать до 16 пар чисел. То есть, ей на вход подается два массива по 16 байт, а она выдает один такой же на выход. Вот только делает она это сильно быстрее. Я использовал ее аналог, который складывает 4 пары 4-байтовых чисел и у меня получилось в 2.5 раза быстрее вычисления (да, пришлось немного цикл поправить, чтобы брать числа группами).

Еще ближе к делу. Как это использовать в своем коде. Вначале нужно в include добавить `emmintrin.h` и все, можно писать код. Вот маленький пример, как просто сложить два числа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() {
      unsigned char a[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = { 200 };            
      unsigned char b[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = { 70 };
      __m128i l = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)a);
      __m128i r = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)b);
      __m128i res =  _mm_adds_epu8(l, r);
      _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a, res);
      std::cout << (int)a[0] << std::endl;
      return 0;
}
```

А теперь сравните, как складываются 7 чисел:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() {
      unsigned char a[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = { 200, 1, 255, 255, 1, 2, 3 };
      unsigned char b[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = { 70, 255, 255, 0, 3, 2, 1};
      __m128i l = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)a);
      __m128i r = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)b);  
      __m128i res =  _mm_adds_epu8(l, r);
      _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a, res);
      for (int i = 0; i<16; i++) {
          std::cout << (int)a[i] << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Эти два примера компилируются под gcc 4.9.3 и работают как ожидается. Обратите особое внимание на странную конструкцию `__attribute__ ((aligned (16)))` Это нужно, чтобы адрес массива в памяти был выравнен по адресу, кратному 16.  Без этого многие sse функции либо просто не работают, выдавая странные ошибки во время исполнения, либо работают сильно-сильно медленее.

И напоследок код для vs2015. В ней выравнивание для массивов делается немного по другому.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() {
    __declspec(align(16)) unsigned char a[16]  = { 200 };
    __declspec(align(16)) unsigned char b[16]  = { 70 };
    __m128i l = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)a);
    __m128i r = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)b);

    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a, _mm_adds_epu8(l, r));
    std::cout << (int)a[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Функция складывает 16 чисел. Но что, если нам нужно сложить только два? Ничего страшного, просто пусть там будет себе мусор, на общую производительность это не влияет. В данном конкретном случае наверно накладные расходы на складывания одного числа могут быть сопоставимы с обычным кодом с `if`. Но если в цикле складывать по 16 пар чисел, то думаю, что производительность можно поднять в 5-10 раз. Но это уже сильно зависит от окружающего кода.

Бонус. [Ссылка на сайт Intel со списком всех доступных функций](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).

Comment: можно использовать [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), чтобы не полагаться на платформозависимый код.

Comment: да, можно. Только для gcc придется указать `-std=c++11` или выше.

Comment: ну да, просто на мой взгляд, в 2016 году, стоит по умолчанию указывать решение с C++11(хотя бы), а платформозависимые либо упоминать по желанию автора, либо сноской.

Comment: оно то логично, но почему тогда ни gcc, ни clang никак не сделают это по умолчанию? А потом ещё рассказывать автору вопроса, как в его компиляторе включить поддержку стандарта...

Comment: они не делают по умолчанию просто потому, что проекты могут перестать собираться от смены версии. Сомнительно конечно, но может быть. В студии нет такого флага и вроде все живы.

Comment: В тексте ответа вы указали функцию _mm_adds_epi8, а в коде используете  _mm_adds_epu8. Поясню автору вопроса, что первая складывает числа со знаком (то есть от -128 до 127), а вторая - без знака (от 0 до 255).

Comment: поправил это дело.

Comment: Здорово! Побудили меня посмотреть в эту сторону (поддержка компилятором векторных операций) и теперь могу поделиться с коллегами [gcc Vector-Extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions)

Comment: Я в ответе упоминал, что GCC поддерживается:)

Answer (score 4):

Во первых - если вообще нельзя использовать сравнение, то сделать желаемое не получится.

Допустим нам можно использовать булевые операторы (больше-меньше). Тогда без `if` и тернарного оператора можно обойтись, заменяя условное выражение безусловным при использовании битовых операций. В вашей ситуации вместо `if`-a можно записать так

```
С = 0xFF ^ ((С^0xFF)&(-(С < 0xFF)));
```

Хотелось бы добавить что подобные выражения очень плохо сказываются на читаемости и сопровождаемости кода, использоваться могут лишь в крайних случаях как самый последний этап оптимизации, и то только в том случае, если будет результат - современные компиляторы могут оптимизировать код в безусловный используя, например, команду `CMOV`.

Answer (score 0):

предполагаю что B можно делить на степени 10 и каждый раз складывать частное с А, одновременно проверяя A на overflow.