# Векторное сложение, SSE

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Имеется `dword` число - RGBA пиксель. Нужно сложить его с другим пикселем (арифметика с насыщением saturation), причем сделать это через регистры `xmm`, упаковав эти `dword'ы` в 128 бит

```
unsigned int A0 = 0xFF99AA00;
unsigned int B0 = 0xFF80AA00;
unsigned int C0 = 0xFF60AA00;
unsigned int D0 = 0xFF70AA00;

unsigned int A1 = 0xFF90AA00;
unsigned int B1 = 0xFF80AA00;
unsigned int C1 = 0xFFB0AA00;
unsigned int D1 = 0xFFC0AA00;


_asm
{
   /*........*/
   PADDUSB xmm1, xmm2
}
```

Как правильно упаковать  4 + 4 `dword` так, чтобы они складывались как 16 + 16 `byte` ?
На месте `/*...*/` нужны соответствующие ассемблерные инструкции для SSE2.
Сумма этих `byte` не может быть больше 255.

---

И еще маленькй вопрос: как можно было бы упаковать 16 char-ов, т.е. если бы для каждого цвета была бы отдельная переменная?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496577/178678, тут как раз то, что вам надо уже готовое и без ассемблерного кода.

Comment: Почему Вы не приняли ни одного ответа в своём прошлом вопросе? Думаете кто-то захочет давать Вам ответы, если Вы не принимаете их?

Comment: @ixSci все ответы подходят. Нужно выбрать лучшей среди них?

Comment: @neko69, нужно выбрать тот, который Вам подошёл, который Вы использовали. Либо же тот, который больше всего понравился. Всегда нужно выбирать ответ, либо же обновлять вопрос, если ни  один не подходит. Вопросы без принятых ответов портят статистику сайта.

Comment: Что касается этого вопроса: в ответах на предыдущий вопрос, KoVadim дал ответ на этот, разве нет? Там есть все нужные интринсики чтобы сложить два массива char размером в 16 байтов каждый. Ваши 4 dword'а это просто частный случай

Comment: хочу понять как это сделать на asm-е

Comment: Интринсики это минимальная надстройка над асмом. Точнее это голый асм, который просто спрятан под C-функции, чтобы было удобнее рабоатать

Comment: по мне инстринки выглядят куда более ужасно, чем сам асм. То, что в прошлом вопросе было сделано через инстринки - я сделал вставкой из 3х строчек асма

Comment: Так ведь в предыдущем ответе был ответ на этот вопрос, если Вам удалось переписать всё, что там есть 3-мя строчками асма, то в чём заключается этот вопрос?

Comment: Кроме того, я сейчас проверил: один интринсик это одна ассемблерная команда, поэтому сократить тот пример Вы не могли. Вот Вам [ссылка](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) на сайт Intel, где можно найти соответствие интринсиков и команд ассемблера